# Android - which Permissions are "special" for Google Play?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

When I add the permissions

```
"INTERNET"
"ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

to my app and upload it to Google Play, people who download the app see the message "this app doesn't require any special permissions".

Are the following permissions "special" for Google Play?

```
"ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
"READ_PHONE_STATE"
```

I'm using a mobile ad SDK that claims to perform better if it is granted all four permissions. But I don't want to scare off some users by asking for too many permissions.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Are you trying to include as much as you can without asking for permissions?  If you need a permission, then you should include it.  Otherwise, don't include the permission.

Comment: There is another similar question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339743/android-permissions-how-can-i-learn-which-are-dangerous-vs-normal

Answer (score 2):

The permission `READ_PHONE_STATE` has to be accepted by users, `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` doesn't.

Somebody asked already about the link between [Android Permissions and Permission Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644625/link-between-android-permissions-and-permission-groups) - the selected answer links [to the actual mapping file](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) for the permissions of Android.

So the permissions you mentioned are belonging into the following groups and protection levels:

- `INTERNET`: NETWORK (dangerous)
- `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`: NETWORK (normal)
- `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`: NETWORK (normal)
- `READ_PHONE_STATE`: PHONE_CALLS (dangerous)

Based on [Google's explanation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) about the `protectionLevel`, "special permissions" (as you call it) are permissions marked as "dangerous" (as Google calls it).

But hey, `INTERNET` is dangerous! Why aren't users asked about this permission? [Because](http://www.howtogeek.com/190863/androids-app-permissions-were-just-simplified-now-theyre-much-less-secure/).

> Google has also given each app Internet access, effectively removing
>   the Internet access permission. Oh, sure, Android developers still
>   have to declare they want Internet access when putting together the
>   app. But users can no longer see the Internet access permission when
>   installing an app and current apps that don’t have Internet access can
>   now gain Internet access with an automatic update without prompting
>   you.

Comment: I'm not sure that the "normal" protection level is automatically "non-special". For example,  "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" is marked as "normal" but will show as Permission "prevents your device from hibernating" in Google Play.

Comment: @android_422 Now I'm not that sure either...  At http://stackoverflow.com/a/7340762/1436981, CommonsWare suggests that the documentation is wrong about this point: `What this may have morphed into is that dangerous permissions are always displayed and normal permissions are ones that might be "below the fold" if there are enough dangerous ones.`